# What exception does S3 throw if you try to manipulate an object that is current being manipulated?

Tags: python, exception, amazon-s3, boto

I am writing a piece of code that copies an S3 object from one key to another. This code sits behind an API endpoint, so it is possible that it is called multiple times while the copy operation is ongoing.

It is my understanding that the S3 copy operation is atomic (according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectsExamples.html).

So I assume an exception will be thrown if I try to initiate a copy operation to a key that is currently being copied to. What exception might that be?

The closest thing I could find is "OperationAborted" but I want to be sure and I don't have a good way of triggering this case myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to S3 documentation:

> Updates to a single key are atomic. For example, if you PUT to an existing key, a subsequent read might return the old data or the updated data, but it never returns corrupted or partial data.

Also note that:

> Amazon S3 does not currently support object locking for concurrent updates. If two PUT requests are simultaneously made to the same key, the request with the latest timestamp wins. If this is an issue, you will need to build an object-locking mechanism into your application.

[More on the S3 consistency model.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel)

This might also explain that, as of now, you can only catch a handful of Client exceptions (but not resource) thru `botocore`. These are:

- S3.Client.exceptions.BucketAlreadyExists
- S3.Client.exceptions.BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou
- S3.Client.exceptions.NoSuchBucket
- S3.Client.exceptions.NoSuchKey
- S3.Client.exceptions.NoSuchUpload
- S3.Client.exceptions.ObjectAlreadyInActiveTierError
- S3.Client.exceptions.ObjectNotInActiveTierError

More details on the above can be found [here](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client-exceptions).

In other words, as long as the copied key is there, there shouldn't be any exception, as you can concurrently access it and copy it to wherever you need it to be.

If, on the other hand, you keep updating the copied key, as stated above, you might end up copying stale data, as S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES in all Regions.